# Fibonacci sequence in Java using for statements

Tags: java, for-loop, fibonacci

I tried making a Java program executing the Fibonacci sequence.

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Fibonacci{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        BufferedReader Data=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int ctr1=0;
        int ctr2=0;
        int num1=0;
        int num2=0;
        int num3=0;
        try{
            System.out.println("How many numbers would you want to see?");
            ctr2=Integer.parseInt(Data.readLine());
            for(int ans=0; ctr1==ctr2; ctr1++){
            num1++;
            System.out.println(num2 + "\n" + num1);
            ans=num1+num2;
            System.out.println(ans);
            ans=num3;
            }
        }catch(IOException err){
            System.out.println("Error!" + err);
        }catch(NumberFormatException err){
            System.out.println("Invald Input!");
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I'm a beginner in Java and I don't know how to properly use the for statement. Would somebody be kind enough to make my code work? Or maybe make a way shorter code that works. I'm a beginner so be cool. Thanks :)

Comment: A first start would be to format your code properly and give your variables proper names.

Answer (score 1):

Fibonacci series in java is actually quite simple and can be done with just one single for-loop!!!!

```
import java.io.*;
class fibonacci{    
    public static void main() throws NumberFormatException, IOException{  
        BufferedReader Data=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int a,b,c,d;
        System.out.println("Upto How many numbers do you want to see?");
        d=Integer.parseInt(Data.readLine());
        for  (a=0,b=1,c=a;a<d;c=a,a+=b,b=c){            
            System.out.println(a);        
        }            
    }
}
```

This has been done using buffered reader........ If you are said to use only bufferedreader go for this else you can use Scanner class which is much simple and easy to use because you don't have to catch or throw any exceptions.....

Scanner program:-

```
import java.util.*;
class fibonacci{    
    public static void main(){  
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b,c;
        System.out.println("Upto How many numbers do you want to see?");
        d=sc.nextInt();
        for  (a=0,b=1,c=a;a<d;c=a,a+=b,b=c){            
            System.out.println(a);        
        }            
    }
}
```

Now as I said in one loop you can do it.... Here is another method where you do the swapping inside the body of the loop and not in the arguments of it...
And this is much simplier to understand for beginners as u don't have to pass multiple variables inside the arguments and yeah its a bit longer

```
import java.util.*;
class fibonacci{    
    public static void main(){  
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0,b = 1,c,d;
        System.out.println("Upto How many numbers do you want to see?");
        d=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a +"\n" +b);//\n is used to go to next line....
        for  (c=0;c<d;c++){  
            c = a + b;//Doing and printing the fibonacci...
            System.out.println(c);     
            a = b;
            b = c;//Swapping the values...
        }            
    }
}
```

So here i have given you three methods that should give the same output(Most probably) choose whichever is convenient for you..

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code snippet which is much easier than yours to understand. Solution tip is simple, you keep 2 pointers for the first 2 fibonacci numbers and update them appropriately in the loop. In the example below, the loop executes 10 times, you can modify it as desired.

```
static void fibonacci() {
    int ptr1 = 1, ptr2 = 1;
    int temp = 0;
    System.out.print(ptr1 + " " + ptr2 + " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(ptr1 + ptr2 + " ");
        temp = ptr1;
        ptr1 = ptr2;
        ptr2 = temp + ptr2;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answers, if you want to look really cool use recursion.

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public static long fib(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) return n;
        else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 300; // how many numbers you want to generate
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ": " + fib(i));
    }
}
```

Here is Google search of what it is, hope those resources help: http://bit.ly/1cWxhUS

Comment: if `n < 0` fibonacci is not defined :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner in java as well however I've found an easy way to create a Fibonacci number using an array.  The basic principle of a Fibonacci number is the addition of the current number and the number that came before.
  **Here is my code:**

```
//Creation of array 
int [ ] fib = new int[size];

//Assigning values to the first and second indexes of array named "fib"
fib [0] = 0;
fib [1] = 1;

//Creating variable "a" to use in for loop
int a = 1

//For loop which creates a Fibonacci number
for( int i = 2; i < size ; i++)
{   
  fib[i] = a;
  a = fib[i] + fib[i-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another algorithm which I found [online](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms) and I kind of simplified the code from it.

```
public static BigInteger fib(BigInteger x) {
        if (x.intValue() < 0){return x.intValue() % 2 == 0 ?fib(x.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(-1))).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(-1)) : fib(x.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(-1)));}
        int n = Integer.valueOf(x.toString());
        BigInteger a = BigInteger.ZERO,b = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int bit = Integer.highestOneBit(n); bit != 0; bit >>>= 1) {
            BigInteger d = a.multiply(b.shiftLeft(1).subtract(a));
            BigInteger e = a.multiply(a).add(b.multiply(b));
            a = d;
            b = e;
            if ((n & bit) != 0) {
                BigInteger c = a.add(b);
                a = b;
                b = c;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
```

I know there is a chance that you wont understand how to use BigInteger, so I am giving you this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/), just trying to be helpful.

Comment: um... idk if i should make this even more simple

Answer (score 0):

```
Here we get Fibonacci Series up to n.

public static void fibSequence(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x = 0, y = 1; sum < n; x = y, y = sum, sum = x + y) {
            System.out.print(sum + " ");
        }
    }
```

Example:

**Input:** n = 20

**Output:** 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13

Answer (score 0):

more simple way

````
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int first = 1;
    int second = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            System.out.print(first);
        System.out.print("," + second);
        int temp = second;
        second = first + second;
        first = temp;
    }
}```
````

program output :: 1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class sequence1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        sequence1 fs=new sequence1();
        fs.fibonacci(); 
    }
    public void fibonacci() 
    {
        int numb1 = 1;
        int numb2 = 1;
        int temp = 0;

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How Many Terms? (Up To 45)");
        int x=input.nextInt();
        x=x-2;

        System.out.println(numb1);
        System.out.println(numb2);

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(numb1 + numb2 + " ");
            temp = numb1;
            numb1 = numb2;
            numb2 = temp + numb2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try to add some explanation and context to your answer, not just post code.

Answer (score -1):

This function return the fibonacci series

```
/**
     * @param startElement   
     * @param secondElent
     * @param length  :length of fibonacci series
     * @return fibonacciseries : contain the series of fibonacci series
     */
    public int[] createFibonacciSeries(int startElement, int secondElent,
            int length) {
        int fibonacciSeries[] = new int[length];
        fibonacciSeries[0] = startElement;
        fibonacciSeries[1] = secondElent;
        for (int i = 2; i < length; i++) {
            fibonacciSeries[i] = fibonacciSeries[i - 1]
                    + fibonacciSeries[i - 2];
        }

        return fibonacciSeries;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

class MyFibonacci {

    public static void main(String a[]){

         int febCount = 15;
         int[] feb = new int[febCount];
         feb[0] = 0;
         feb[1] = 1;
         for(int i=2; i < febCount; i++){
             feb[i] = feb[i-1] + feb[i-2];
         }

         for(int i=0; i< febCount; i++){
                 System.out.print(feb[i] + " ");
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class FibonacciExercitiu {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int result = fib(6); //here we test the code. Scanner can be implemented.
    System.out.println(result);

}

public static int fib(int n) {

    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 1; //this line is only for declaring z as a variable. the real assignment for z is in the for loop.

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
        z = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = z;

    }

    return z;
}

/*
1.   F(0) = 1 (x)
2.   F(1) = 1.(y) =>Becomes x for point4
3.(z)F(2) = 2 (z) =>Becomes Y for point4 // becomes X for point 5
4.(z)F(3) = 3                            // becomes y for point 5
5.(z)F(4) = 5 ..and so on
*/
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static int[] fibonachiSeq(int n)
 {
     if (n < 0)
         return null;

    int[] F = new int[n+1];

    F[0] = 0;
    if (n == 0)
        return F;
    F[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        F[i] = F[i-1] + F[i-2];
    }



    return F;

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using while loop

```
class Feb
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int fn = 0;
        int sn = 1;
        int tn = 1;

        Console.WriteLine(fn);
        Console.WriteLine(sn);
        while (true)
        {
            tn = fn + sn;

            if (tn >10)
            {
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(tn);
            fn = sn;
            sn = tn;
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually C# rather than Java.

Answer (score -1):

public class Febonacci {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int first =0;
    int secend =1; 
    System.out.print(first+","+secend);
    for (int k=1;k<7;k++){
        System.out.print(","+(first+secend ));
        if(k%2!=0)
            first+=secend;
        else 
            secend+=first;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explaination as to what you are doing in this code, what was originally wrong with OP's code and how this is fixing it. The idea of this site is for other people to come across this question later and learn from it

Answer (score -1):

```
public class FibonacciSeries {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=0, c=0, b=1;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            System.out.print(c+" ");
            a = c + b;
            c = b;
            b = a;
        }
    }
}
```